# How to set permisions for git so it runs without sudo

Tags: permissions, git

I have problem with git permisions. When I run git from console i have to add sudo in front of it to get it to work, but when I use NetBeans GUI the script runs without the 'sudo' command and in result I am promped with this error message:

```
[ java.io.IOException: No access ]
```

What do i have to do to make it work ?

Permision of my /var/www/html/apps/blog directory content

```
wiktor@wiktor-VB:/var/www/html/apps/blog$ ls -la
all 140
drwxr-xr-x  9 wiktor wiktor  4096 lis 27 23:28 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 wiktor wiktor  4096 lis 27 21:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 wiktor wiktor  4096 lis 27 21:34 app
drwxr-xr-x  2 wiktor wiktor  4096 lis 27 21:33 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 wiktor wiktor  2318 lis 23 13:18 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 wiktor wiktor 64050 lis 23 13:18 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  8 root   root    4096 lis 27 22:23 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 wiktor wiktor   204 lis 27 23:28 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 wiktor wiktor  1065 lis 23 13:18 LICENSE
drwxrwxr-x  3 wiktor wiktor  4096 lis 27 23:28 nbproject
-rw-r--r--  1 wiktor wiktor  2448 lis 23 13:18 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  3 wiktor wiktor  4096 lis 23 13:18 src
-rw-r--r--  1 wiktor wiktor  1308 lis 23 13:18 UPGRADE-2.2.md
-rw-r--r--  1 wiktor wiktor  1962 lis 23 13:18 UPGRADE-2.3.md
-rw-r--r--  1 wiktor wiktor   356 lis 23 13:18 UPGRADE-2.4.md
-rw-r--r--  1 wiktor wiktor  8499 lis 23 13:18 UPGRADE.md
drwxr-xr-x 14 wiktor wiktor  4096 lis 27 21:34 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  3 wiktor wiktor  4096 lis 27 21:34 web
```

Comment: What does Brak dostępu mean?

Comment: oh sorry! :) shame on me. It means access denied

Comment: or simple no permisions  to execute this command from NetBeans GUI

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/bin/git` give back?

Comment: It returns: 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1773392 lip 30 13:22 /usr/bin/git

Comment: my project is located in: /var/www/html/apps/blog

Comment: What are the permissions on /var/ww/html/ and subdirectories?

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you can see in your ls output, the `.git` directory is owned by root, and you don't have write access to it. Fix it with this command:

```
sudo chown -R wiktor:wiktor /var/www/html/apps/blog/.git
```

This will transfer file ownership of the git directory and everything in it back to you.

Comment: It works. Tahank you for your time and help !

Comment: Thanks, took a while to find this but it works.